# ios sdk noob - including, text, images and links in one view

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I'm making a popup, and I want to include a scrolling box inside the popup that contains a lot of text, images, and hyperlinks to the internet.   I am doing this all programatically and was considering adding many different subviews to a UIView and then making that a subview of UIScrollview..

it just seems to be a lot of things to keep track of.  spacing between labels, textviews, images, etc.. and then keeping track of those dimensions for use with a scrollview.  what is the ideal way to present all these things while minimizing busy work?

Comment: When you say 'popup' what do you mean? A UIAlertView? A UIPopoverController? And have you considered using Interface Builder/Storyboards? Interface Builder keeps track of all those dimensions you're talking about so you don't have to.

Comment: im creating a uiview programatically and animating it into my superview. that is the popup.  then that popup contains a scrollview.. inside of THAT scrollview is where i want to put all my content..  i didnt want to do it in IB since I already have a lot of clutter there.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you might benefit from using a UITableView.

Comment: i dont really think this would work at all.  i want something like .. a pragraph of text. an image, another paragraph.. a link, another image.  etc.  think wikipedia

Comment: you'd be surprised at how powerful a UITableView can be. fully customizable and easily implemented. based off your needs i still believe its your best bet.